# How do I know if Game Center is down or not?

Tags: icloud, game-center

I'm not *asking to know **now***, but wondering if Apple has a status page that lists if Game Center is having problems. I'm aware of the [iCloud system status web page](http://www.apple.com/support/icloud/systemstatus/) but it's not clear to me if that is the place where Game Center would be listed if for some reason it was not operating fully or correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>No, I have suffered some Game Center outages in the past, but could not find a source directly from Apple which stated so, not even the iCloud status page.</s>

The [iCloud System Status page](http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/) now lists the status for all Apple internet services, including Game Center.

Comment: That service isn't update fast enough, takes about 6-12 hrs of service being down before it shows up on the status page.

Comment: @Kenny I agree - Apple seems to do a poor job of explaining when services are not running at full speed. That status page is more like "total meltdown - no chance anyone can use it" instead of "we're seeing increased error rates and slow service times" kind of thing. After using this service for 8 years, it’s hard to quantify when it’s slow to fail or something else is up. Monitoring in the last 3 years seems pretty fair and responsive but I’m mostly in the US.